# Why should primary keys of DB not be shown in html code, e.g. in select fields?

Tags: html, database-design, security, datamodel

anywhere I read that values in select boxes (or anything else in the html code) should not be the primary key of the database table. For example:

```
<select>
       <option value="1">Value 1</option>
       <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

In the database there are lookup tables with these values as primary key (1, 2, 3,....). So the data from the select box I store in a table which references this lookup table is a number like 1, 2, 3.... (as the value of the options fields).
I read to better not use the same values in html and as key due to security reasons, but what's the matter with that? I don't understand why this should be a security reason?

Comment: I think it's a load of hooey in this example.

Comment: Where did you read about the security issue?

Comment: Indeed, where did you read about this? Only concern which comes to mind is portability for the case that those options are hardcoded. Other concern is SQL injection, but that's not strictly related to using PK's as option values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [security-through-obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), aka no security at all to me.

A good primary key in a database is purely for uniqueness in the system and shouldn't be related to the meaning of the data. If the primary key *was* related to the data (say people's social security numbers, stuff like that) then you've got a security issue in exposing the keys, as they are exposing information that *could* be used maliciously. In that case, whilst you could argue that the best approach from a technical point of view might be to change the application to stop it using those meaningful keys, it may be a more palatable approach to map the keys to some other meaningless key to overcome the issue.

Another scenario that springs to mind where exposing the keys might be interpreted as a security issue is where inadequate authentication and authorisation is in place for writable data in your application/data layer, allowing someone with knowledge of those keys to interfere with the data in the application. Again, securing the system is the better approach.

Aside from security, I can't think of a specific issue if the keys really do identify the data being interacted with and your application is looking up the keys when it generates the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned about how the information is processed from the URL. What happens if I posted content using value="does_this_break_the_code" or value="can_I_read_secret_info"

Comment: That's what I always recheck in the code before I save it to the database.

Comment: If the code is checked for these security issues then the potential security hole has been filled. Sadly you may be questioned by people who are unaware of "what" the potential holes are and only know that if the PID is used in a form there is a potential ...

Answer (score 1):

It would be wise to exercise caution in using *surrogate* keys in URLs or in HTML or application code. I wouldn't say the same thing about keys in general.

A surrogate key is not supposed to have business meaning or to have dependencies in application code or external processes. That's often an important consideration for example if key values need to change as a result of the database design evolving or data sets being merged. By using surrogate keys as "magic numbers" in code or in URLs you could compromise the very thing that makes surrogate keys useful. Also surrogate keys are much less convenient to users (and possibly developers) because the values are meaningless to them and therefore less readable than using a natural key.

I suggest you use natural keys in your URLs and persistent code. Keep surrogate keys internal to the database, which is where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys should be used as a unique identifier for each item in the DB, chances are it isn't a part number or anything that relates to the actual item. Generally speaking the PK doesn't MEAN anything, and in the world of semantics, everything should mean something. If there is a better unique identifier, by all means use it, because your PK isn't helpful to anything but your database.

Say you have a database of cars, all cars have a unique identifier called a VIN (Vehicle Identification Number) in the VIN is encoded a bunch of info about each specific car down to the plant that made it. The VIN only identifies that one specific car. the PK on the item could be anything, the car gets dropped from the DB, now the PK doesn't exist, but that VIN is still out there somewhere. It's a much better unique ID than the PK, so that's what should probably be displayed to the users.